# Keycloak unable to get access token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, keycloak

I'm trying to use `AuthzClient` to obtain an access token from a public client in my Spring app.

Here is the code:

```
AuthzClient authzClient = AuthzClient.create();
AuthorizationRequest request = new AuthorizationRequest();
AuthorizationResponse response = authzClient.authorization(username, password)
                                .authorize(request);
String token = response.getToken();
```

But I keep getting this error message:

> org.keycloak.authorization.client.util.HttpResponseException: Unexpected response from server: 400 / Bad Request / Response from server: {"error":"invalid_request","error_description":"Client does not support permissions"}

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: There are multiple ways to retrieve keycloak token. Are you specifically looking to obtain token through `AuthzClient ` or are open to other ways?

Answer (score 6):

First you need to enable authorization service for your client. So you should go to your client settings page on the admin console and click the `Authorization Enabled` switch to `ON`, and then click `Save` button.

See also:
[Keycloak Authorization Services Guide - 2.3. Enabling Authorization Services](https://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/authorization_services/index.html#_getting_started_hello_world_enabling_authz_services)